# What are the healthiest foods I can feed my small dog?

Tags: dogs, health, diet, feeding

There are a lot of reports about bad dog food, but seldom a credible one on healthy dog foods.

What are the best things I can feed my dog to make sure she lives a long healthy life ?

Comment: This question is far too broad and primarily opinion based. _Healthy_ is a highly subjective qualifier and in addition to that the question polls for a list of things rather than a specific answer.

Comment: there are plenty of questions on the site about dietary advice and treats for pets, turtles etc. I don't see why this should be closed

Comment: There are too many variables, age and breed of the dog being two big ones.  It is still to broad.

Answer (score 5):

Listing particular products for you will not be helpful. As with most carnivorous pets, what I can suggest is to consider that the ingredients of the food really, really, matter. Dogs are ***not*** meant to eat corn or wheat, but many dog food contain some volume of these as filler and as a means to cut costs.

What you want to look for are dry or wet food choices that are predominantly meat (proteins) and animal fats. These will help your dog to be healthy and happy, but these choices are also more expensive.  You'll typically need to go to a dedicated pet store than a grocery store to purchase them.